# Is there a way to unzip a file while simultaneously check the file currently being unzipped?

Tags: java, bash

I'm trying to unzip a huge zip file(multiple GBs) full of JSON files. I want to keep only the files that contains the tags `foo=1`.

I've tried to unzip the whole thing with the `unzip` command, then process the data, but there's storage restrictions. I'm trying to see if there's a way to simultaneously unzip these files, and

1. check each file that's being unzipped
2. if the file doesn't contain `foo=1`, delete the file
3. repeat for all files

I couldn't find a way to do it without unzipping the entire thing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Ideally it would be a bash command, but if there's a way to do it in java I would be grateful for it too

Thanks!

Comment: The `ZipInputStream` approach did not work for me. looks like my file is `tar` and not a `zip` file

Answer (score 1):

with `java` you can do it like this

```java
public void unzipFile(String zip, String dest) throws Exception {
  String fileZip = Paths.get(zip).toString();
  File destDir = Paths.get(dest).toFile();
  if (!destDir.exists()) {
    destDir.mkdir();
  }
  ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileZip));
  ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
  while (zipEntry != null) {
    File newFile = Paths.get(destDir.getAbsolutePath(), zipEntry.getName()).toFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    // read the contents of the file
    StringBuilder fileContents = readAllFileContents(zis);
    // test if the contents are valid
    if (isValid(fileContents)) {
      fos.write(fileContents.toString().getBytes());
      fos.close();
    }
    zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
  }
  zis.closeEntry();
  zis.close();
}

private boolean isValid(StringBuilder fileContents) {
  return fileContents.toString().contains("foo=1");
}

private StringBuilder readAllFileContents(ZipInputStream zis) throws IOException {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1 << 10];
  int len;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, len));
  }
  return sb;
}
```